# Python 3 Index Error

Tags: python, list, python-3.5, anagram

Consider the following code:

```
def anadist(string1, string2):
    string1_list = []
    string2_list = []

    for i in range(len(string1)):
        string1_list.append(string1[i])
    for i in range(len(string2)):
        string2_list.append(string2[i])

    # Test returns for checking
    # return (string1_list,string2_list)
    # return len(string1_list)
    # return len(string2_list)

    for i in range(0,len(string1_list)):
        try:
            if (string1_list[i]) in string2_list:
                com = string1_list.pop(i)
                com_index = string2_list.index(com)
                string2_list.pop(com_index)
            else:
                pass
        except ValueError:
            pass
    return string1_list


def main():
    str1 = input("Enter string #1 >>> ")
    str2 = input("Enter string #2 >>> ")
    result = anadist(str1, str2)
    print(result)

#Boilerplate Check
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running in Python 3.5.2 raises an IndexError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\CSE107L\Practice\anadist.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\CSE107L\Practice\anadist.py", line 29, in main
    result = anadist(str1, str2)
  File "E:\CSE107L\Practice\anadist.py", line 15, in anadist
    if (string1_list[i]) in string2_list:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And I can't find what is going wrong. I wrote another code similar and that works:

```
def main():
    lst = [1,2,3,4,5]
    lst2 = [5,6,7,8,9]
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        if lst[i] in lst2:
            com = lst.pop(i)
            lst2_index = lst2.index(com)
            lst2.pop(lst2_index)
        else:
            pass
    print(lst)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I feel the error is coming from the way I am forming `string1_list`. This code is for how many steps it takes to form an anagram of a pair of words.

Comment: You can not remove an element in a list when you are iterating the list. In your codes, the list is `string1_list`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In some cases, you are shortening `string_list1` while you're iterating over it:

```
if (string1_list[i]) in string2_list:
    com = string1_list.pop(i)  # string1_list gets shorter here
```

However, your `range` doesn't change.  It's still going to go from `0` until it counts up to the *original* length of `string1_list` (exclusive).  This will cause the `IndexError` any time `string1_list.pop(i)` is called.

One possible solution would be to use a `while` loop instead:

```
i = 0
while i < len(string1_list):
    try:
        if string1_list[i] in string2_list:
            com = string1_list.pop(i)
            com_index = string2_list.index(com)
            string2_list.pop(com_index)
        else:
            pass
    except ValueError:
        pass
    i += 1
```

This will cause the loop termination condition to be checked after each iteration.  If you remove some elements from `string1_list`, it'll still be OK because the loop will terminate before `i` gets big enough to overrun the bounds of it's container.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are mutating the `string1_list` within the `for` loop by performing `string1_list.pop(i)`. The length of the list is being reduced within the `for` loop by doing `string1_list.pop(i)`, but you are still iterating over the length of the original list.

Your second lot of code works only because you only `pop` on the last iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt works simply because a "match" is found only in the last element `5` and as such when you mutate your list `lst` it is during the *last iteration* and has no effect.

The problem with your first attempt is that you might remove from the beginning of the list. The counter doesn't get updated and at some point might reach a value that no longer exists in the list (it has been popped). Try running it with no matches in the input and see that it works.

In general, *don't mutate your list while iterating through it*. Instead of the:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
    # mutate list
```

'idiom', you should opt for the:

```
for i in list(list_object):   # or for i in list_object[:]:
```

which makes a copy first and allows you to mutate the original `list_object` by keeping mutating and looping separate.